# Cannot insert data into MySQL database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm setting up a dashboard and need users to be able to see their session history for security purposes. So I decided to create a database  and use PHP to insert the `session_id()`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and some other variables into the table, but for some reason PHP and/or MySQL is not able to `INSERT` the values into the database. I'm able to read and display data from that same database, but I'm not able to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the data.

The server I'm working on is running Apache 2, PHP 7, and MySQL 5. I've tried inserting and updating data in the past (and on other servers) but I always run into this problem.

```
$badge_number = $_SESSION['badge_number'];

$session_id = session_id();

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', '*********', 'database');

   if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Cannot connect to database");
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO `session_log` (`id`, `badge_number`, `session_id`, `session_start`, `session_end`, `session_length`) VALUES (NULL, $badge_number, $session_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, 'regular')";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die('Error code:' . mysqli_error());
    } else {
        header("Location: /overview?message=%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ESuccess%21%3C/strong%3EYou%20have%20successfully%20logged%20in%20and%20inserted%20a%20new%20row%20in%20the%20session%20log%21%3C/p%3E&messagecolor=green&messageid=3942791098282");
    }
```

I expect to see a new row in the database each time a user logs in, but I keep getting this error message `Error code:`, which doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186895/discussion-on-question-by-heather-w-cannot-insert-data-into-mysql-database-via).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session ID is a string, so you'll need to add a single quote around `$session_id` to your SQL on the `VALUES` side like this:

```
$badge_number = $_SESSION['badge_number'];

$session_id = session_id();

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', '*********', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Cannot connect to database");
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `session_log` (`id`, `badge_number`, `session_id`, `session_start`, `session_end`, `session_length`) VALUES (NULL, $badge_number, '$session_id', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, 'regular')";
//added single quotes around '$session_id' above on the VALUES side. 

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Error code:' . mysqli_error());
} else {
    header("Location: /overview?message=%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3ESuccess%21%3C/strong%3EYou%20have%20successfully%20logged%20in%20and%20inserted%20a%20new%20row%20in%20the%20session%20log%21%3C/p%3E&messagecolor=green&messageid=3942791098282");
}
```